# write as a single fraction in its simplest form.

Tags: calculus, fractions, partial-fractions

I've been given this problem to solve and a little confused on how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the problem I need to solve:

$$55+\frac{x^5}{(x-6)(x+1)}-\frac{7x}{x+6}.$$

Comment: After a reduction of fractions, you just need to check if any factor of the denominator is a factor of numerator.

Comment: What is confusing you ?